# What is the brand and model of this AT chassis case from the early 90s?

Tags: history, hardware, identify-this-computer

A friend is trying find the original brand and model of this old 1990’s generic case.   An ad from computershopper would help.

[image: 1990’s AT Computer Case]

Comment: This is most likely to be a white box PC built by an independent shop.

Comment: there must have been thousands of case variations from that era.

Comment: Yep, abd there are probably thousands here on retrocomputing that purchased this case and some probably remember the supplier.

Comment: Are there on-line resources of Computer Shopper and other magazines of the 1990's?  The Archive.Org has a few Computer Shopper magazines on-line, but nothing in the 1990s.  A visual search might turn up a few possible leads.

Answer (score 7):

I doubt there is any brand or model to be found, as this is a middle of the road no name case, produced by some Asian, most likely Taiwanese, company, sold in bulk as commodity. These companies did never intend to build a brand at all as this would have worked against their sales.

Even more so, these case manufacturers were often themselves relying on random suppliers, so the look was defined by what front plates they could buy from a front plate manufacturer. Various manufacturers were supplied by the same front plate company. It was a pure capitalist world of copying. And competition meant as well that front plate companies copied moulds from each other.

If it's about finding the 'right' sticker that was on there, it's even more random. It could have been from the box manufacturer (unlikely, the shop configuring the PC (larger ones did do their own), the mainboard manufacturer - during the 90s and early noughties mainboard manufacturers delivered stickers with their products - or CPU manufacturers who did alike. Many ways one could show off.

Bottom line: **Without having any explicit trace, it's impossible to give a hint for either - even finding similar cases won't do it.**

Comment: I'm not disagreeing, but there _are_ some case manufacturers that stand out.  Enlight was big in the 90's and I know at least that FastMicro shipped a bazillion of them.  I found a fantastic pic linked on vogons.org - http://imageshack.com/i/eyo2w7crj - and I am sure many RCSE members will recognize these.  Of course, none of this is helpful to the OP, but at least he can (probably) rule-out Enlight.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a discussion on [Vogons](https://www.vogons.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=72556) from a person called Firage with the same case. You might be able to get in touch with them via that site and ask.

[image]

Comment: In fact if you read the thread there's two people on there that had it.